# How does GSL-shell compare to Torch

Tags: lua, scientific-computing, gsl, torch

It looks that [Lua Torch](http://torch.ch/) supersedes [GSL Shell](http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/), especially with the [iTorch](https://github.com/facebook/iTorch) package. How do they compare to each other? When someone will like to use GSL Shell vs Torch? Are they compatible (can one use GSL Shell objects in Torch functions)?